# Adding File Extensions into Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, png

I am using a wordpress plugin on my website called "Simple Job Board"
In the job board, users are able to upload resumes and this plugin only allows .txt, .pdf, .doc, etc. type of documents to be uploaded... However, I want png's to be uploaded as well.

I went to the php script and added these lines.

```
  <option <?php
                        $selected = ( 'no' === 
  get_option('job_board_all_extensions_check') ) ? ( FALSE !== 
  get_option('job_board_upload_file_ext') ) ? (in_array('png', 
  get_option('job_board_upload_file_ext')) ? 'selected' : '' ) : '' : 
  'selected';
                        echo $selected
                        ?> value="png"><?php echo esc_html__('png', 'simple-
job-board'); ?></option>
```

However, png's are still not an option when trying to upload files.
Is there possibly somewhere else I'd have to 'declare' png's as an uploadable extension?

Comment: Nope. It will be in the plugin code itself.

Comment: @Joseph, Please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Comment: @Joseph, please check my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Put below updated code in function.php

Please take db backup and apply this code.

```
update_option('job_board_allowed_extensions',array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'rtf', 'txt', 'png'));
update_option('job_board_upload_file_ext',array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'rtf', 'txt', 'png'));
```

Hope this help.

Comment: will deactivating the plugin cause me to lose my current settings?

Comment: I was able to get the png extension option to show in the desired field, however users still cannot upload png's they get a notification saying that this extension type is not accepted

Comment: It's working from my side, i can upload png file also after follow the above steps.

Comment: so I removed the  " if ( is_plugin_active( 'simple-job-board/simple-job-board.php' ) )  " statement and entered the update_options into the end of my function.php script but still no luck... png's are displayed in uploadable file extensions but are not actually accepted when trying to upload png files... is there somewhere else that I should enter code to allow png uploads

Comment: going into the function.php does not work, this is a plugin specific problem that needs to be addressed directly in the plugin script. your code may be correct but adding it in the function.php file did not help

Comment: @joseph : if code is correct then you should accept the answer for developer encouragement.